# What is the name of the function to see the plots with every x variables against the y variables?

Tags: r

I forgot the name of it. But in r, I could see every plot with every x variables against y variable at one time? But if I have lots of x variables, the result image was too huge to recognize. Besides, I couldn't enlarge the image. Is there any good way to get the results at one time and see every result with clear image?

Comment: referring to Graphing functions ??

Comment: Do you mean `plot.data.frame`? As in `plot(mtcars)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're possibly recalling the default `plot` method acting on a `data.frame` which plots a matrix of pairwise columns.

```r
plot(iris)
```

[image]

If you want to restrict which columns are involved, you subset the `data.frame` first

```
plot(iris[, c(2,3,4)])
```

[image]

If you wish to view it larger, you can either enlarge the image window (whatever system you're using) or save the image at a high resolution.

Alternatively, `pairs` to specify which variables to plot against each other

```r
pairs(iris, horInd = 1, verInd = 1:3)
```

[image]

Comment: what if I want to fix the Y variable?

Comment: `pairs(iris, horInd = 1, verInd = 1:3)` will plot the first column of `iris` (`Sepal.Length`) against the first three columns (the matching case will contain the name of the variable).